# Cannot authenticate to Google Document AI

Tags: cloud-document-ai

I am trying to use Google Document AI for Invoices from our application provider. I have created a Project (which works with Google Vision AI), a Storage Bucket, a Service Account (and gotten a JSON key file), a Processor, but when I go to authenticate I get the following message:

```
Error while trying to connect to the Google DocumentAI Engine. PERMISSION DENIED: Permission 'documentai.processors.processOnline' denied on resource '//documentai.googleapis.com/projects/savvy-container-300718/locations/null/processors/32a7eaa085f61a3b' (or it may not exist).
```

Any ideas on why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

- From the error message, it seems like the processor location is missing (`null`):

  - `.../locations/null/processors/...`.
- Depending on the processor location, the endpoint URL can be:

  - `.../locations/us/processors/...`
  - `.../locations/eu/processors/...`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the service account may not have the correct permission settings